# Django server crashes with exit codes 139, 77

Tags: python, django, libreoffice

### Foreword

Okay, I have a really complex perfomance issue. I'm building a content managment system and one of the features should be generating tons of `.docx` files with different templates. I started with [Webodt](https://pythonhosted.org/django-webodt/quickstart.html) + Abiword. But then templates got too complex, so I had to swith my backend to [Templated-docs](http://templated-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) + LibreOffice. So this is where my problems started.

I use:

- Python 2.7.12
- Django==1.8.2
- templated-docs==0.2.9
- LibreOffice 5.1.5.2
- Ubuntu 16.04

### The actual problem

I have an API which handles `.docx` render. I will show one of views, as an example, they are pretty similar:

```
@permission_classes((permissions.IsAdminUser,))
class BookDocxViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    def retrieve(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = Pupils.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk'])
        serializer = StudentSerializer(queryset)
        context = dict(serializer.data)
        doc = fill_template('crm/docs/book.ott', context, output_format='docx')
        p = u'docs/books/%s/%s_%s_%s.doc' % (datetime.now().date(), context[u'surname'], context[u'name'], datetime.now().date())
        with open(doc, 'rb') as f:
            content = f.read()
            path = default_storage.save(p, ContentFile(content))
            f.close()
        return response.Response(u'/media/' + path)
```

When I call it the first time, it creates a `.docx` file, saves it to my `default_storage` and then returns me a download link. But when I try to do it again, of do it with another method (which works with another template and context), my server just crashes without any logs. The last thing I see is either

1. `Process finished with exit code 77` if I call it with a little delay (more then one second)
2. `Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)` if call my method for the second time right away (in less than one second)

I tried to use debuger -- it said that my server crashes on this line:

`doc = fill_template('crm/docs/book.ott', context, output_format='docx')`

I bet what happens is:

1. When I call my method the first time `templated_docs` starts LibreOffice backend, and then **does not stop it**
2. When I call my method the second time `templated_docs` tries to start LibreOffice backend again, but it is already busy.

### Questions

1. <strike>How do I debug LibreOffice to prove / refute my theory?</strike> *(I guess I need to debug `templated_docs` instead)*
2. Why do I get different exit codes depending of delay?
3. Is it enough base to oppen an [issue](https://github.com/alexmorozov/templated-docs/issues) on GitHub?
4. How do I fix that?

---

### UPD

It is not an issue of REST Framework or not using `FileResponce()`.
I already tried to test it with regular view.

```
def get_document(request, *args, **kwargs):
    context = Pupils.objects.get(id=kwargs['pk']).__dict__
    doc = fill_template('crm/docs/book.ott', context, output_format='docx')
    p = u'%s_%s_%s' % (context[u'surname'], context[u'name'], datetime.now().date())
    return FileResponse(doc, p)
```

And the problem is same.

---

### UPD 2

Okay. This line is chashing my server:

```
# pylokit/lokit.py
self.lokit = lo.libreofficekit_hook(six.b(lo_path))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, that was a bug in `templated_docs`. I was right, it happens because `templated_docs` is trying to start LibreOffice twice. As it said in `pylokit` [documentation](https://github.com/xrmx/pylokit#examples):

> The use of _exit() instead of default exit() is required because in
>   some circumstances LibreOffice segfaults on process exit.

It means the process that used `pylockt` should be killed after. But we cannot kill Django server. So I decided to use multiprocessing:

```
# templated_docs/__init__.py

if source_extension[1:] != output_format:
    lo_path = getattr(
        settings,
        'TEMPLATED_DOCS_LIBREOFFICE_PATH',
        '/usr/lib/libreoffice/program/')

    def f(conn):
        with Office(lo_path) as lo:
            conv_file = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False,
                                           suffix='.%s' % output_format)
            with lo.documentLoad(str(dest_file.name)) as doc:
                doc.saveAs(conv_file.name)
            os.unlink(dest_file.name)
            conn.send(conv_file.name)
            conn.close()

    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(child_conn,))
    p.start()
    conv_file_name = parent_conn.recv()
    p.join()

    return conv_file_name
else:
    return dest_file.name
```

I oppened an [issue](https://github.com/alexmorozov/templated-docs/issues/3) and made a [pull request](https://github.com/alexmorozov/templated-docs/pull/4).